# Google Socialite en Laravel: Undefined index: family_name

Tags: laravel, laravel-7, socialite

Me está pasando con algunas cuentas de Gmail que no pueden registrarse y en los logs me figuran dos problemas:

> Undefined index: family_name {"exception":"[object]
> (ErrorException(code: 0): Undefined index: family_name at
> /home/brooklyn/Sistema/app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php:101)

Que apunta al siguiente fragmento de código: En LoginController

```
if(!$user){
                $user = User::create([
                    'name' => $userSocialite->user['given_name'],
                    'apellido' => $userSocialite->user['family_name'],
                    'email' => $userSocialite->getEmail(),
                    'permiso' => 'USUARIO',
                    'tipo_usuario' => 'PARTICULAR'
                ]);
            }
```

La línea en cuestión es la del apellido.

Alguién sabe a que puede deberse o que se puede probar para solucionar este problema?

**El código completo:**

```
public function handleProviderCallback(Request $request, $driver)
{
    if($request->get('error')){
        return redirect()->route('login')->with('info', 'Ocurrió un error, vuelva a intentarlo más tarde.');
    }

    if (empty($_GET)) {
        $t = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_QUERY);
        parse_str($t, $output);
        foreach ($output as $key => $value) {
            $request->query->set($key, $value);
        }
    }

    $userSocialite = Socialite::driver($driver)->user();

    $social_profile = SocialProfile::where('social_id', $userSocialite->getId())
                                   ->where('social_name', $driver)->first();

    if(!$social_profile){

        $user = User::where('email', $userSocialite->getEmail())->first();
        if(!$user){
            $user = User::create([
                'name' => $userSocialite->user['given_name'],
                'apellido' => $userSocialite->user['family_name'],
                'email' => $userSocialite->getEmail(),
                'permiso' => 'USUARIO',
                'tipo_usuario' => 'PARTICULAR'
            ]);
        }

        $social_profile = SocialProfile::create([
            'user_id' => $user->id,
            'social_id' => $userSocialite->getId(),
            'social_name' => $driver,
            'social_avatar' => $userSocialite->getAvatar()
        ]);

    }

    auth()->login($social_profile->user);

    return redirect()->route('panel');

    /* dd($user->user['given_name']); */

    // $user->token;
}
```

Por ultimo también recibo en los Logs el siguiente problema:

> {"exception":"[object] (Laravel\Socialite\Two\InvalidStateException(code: 0): at /home/brooklyn/Sistema/vendor/laravel/socialite/src/Two/AbstractProvider.php:209)

Muchas gracias por destinar su valioso tiempo en mi consulta valoro mucho cualquier sugerencia.

Comment: Que te devuelve `$userSocialite`?

Comment: Me devuelve el array con los datos del usuario, name, mail, avatar, user y dentro de user -> name, given, family_name etc. pareciera que devuelve bien todos los datos.

Comment: Tengo el mismo problema!, algunas cuentas de email me arrojan: ' Undefined index: "family_name" '
Alguien sabe que puede estar pasando que Google no me retorna un objeto "User" siempre con las mismas propiedades? Muchas gracias!

Comment: Detecte que sólo pasa en algunas cuentas de gmail. Y después de unos usos se reestableció sólo. O por lo menos en mi sitio no tuve quejas. Si encuentras algo agradecería que lo compartas. Yo ahora voy a implementarlo en otro sitio, cualquier cosa te aviso. Saludos